# How do I output the correct value of different strings on different lines?

Tags: c++

Given a string on one line and a second string on the second line, output the index where the second string starts in the first string.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Fuzzy bear
zy
```

the output is:

```
3
```

Note: Using a pre-defined string function, the solution can be just one line of code Butt does not have to be.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
  string workString;
  string string2;
  int pos;

  getline(cin, workString);

  cin >> string2;

  /* Your code goes here */

  cout << pos << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve it, for example to actually *ask* us a question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a question, it's only an exercise that author wants we to do it for him

Answer (score 0):

```
cout << workString.find(String2) << endl;
```

Comment: Please give some explanation why this code answers question asked

Comment: Please phrase this as an explained conditional answer, in order to avoid the impression of asking a clarification question instead of answering (for which a comment should be used instead of an answer, compare https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead ). For example like "If your problem is ... then the solution is to .... because .... ."

Answer (score -1):

we search for the first character of string2 if we found the match in workString then we look for other characters of string2 if we found all characters of string2 in workString in the same order then we assign the pos to j index and then we break the loop.

```
int i = 0;
for (int j = 0; j < workString.size(); ++j) {
    int n = 1;
     if (string2[i] == workString[j]) {
        while(n < workString.size()) {
            if(string2[i+n] == workString[j+n]){
                if ((i+n) == string2.size()) {
                  pos = j;
                  break;
                }
            }
            n++;
        }
     }
}
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)